# Determine the size of Groove Workspaces programmatically?

Tags: .net, groove

Is there a trick in the Groove Web Services to find the size of a Groove Workspace, as displayed on the Properties dialog?  Most of the other information shown here is available, but I can't find size.

Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably seen the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb290881.aspx that describes the attributes of a space. You can see neither the size of the space, nor any info about the local files that store the space.